# Consistency strength of 0-1 valued Borel measures

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, large-cardinals

The following is an overly fancy way of asking a question suggested in [Borel Measures: Atoms vs. Point Masses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987827/borel-measures-atoms-vs-point-masses/987851?noredirect=1#comment2023510_987851)

Let $\phi$ be a property that topological spaces can have (such as "compact", "$T_1$", etc.) and let $M(\phi)$ be the statement "There exists a topological space $X$ with property $\phi$, and a nontrivial, countably additive, 0-1 valued Borel measure on $X$ which is not a point mass."  (For the purposes of this question, a measure $\mu$ is a point mass if there exists $a \in X$ such that $\mu(A) = 1$ iff $a \in A$.)

> For various values of $\phi$, what is the consistency strength of $M(\phi)$?

A few examples:

- $M(\text{compact Hausdorff})$ is a theorem of ZFC (let $X = [0,\omega_1] = \omega_1+1$ with the order topology, and consider the [Dieudonné measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161396/822).)
- $M(\text{finite discrete})$ is inconsistent with ZFC.
- $M(\text{separable metrizable})$ is also inconsistent with ZFC, as I show in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987851/822).
- $M(\text{discrete})$ is implied by "there exists a measurable cardinal", and if I understand the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal) correctly, they are actually equivalent.  It's known that this has greater consistency strength than ZFC but is not known to be inconsistent.

I would be particularly interested in knowing about $M(\text{metrizable})$ and $M(\text{completely metrizable})$.

Comment: I'm not entire sure if that's what you mean, but a real-valued measurable cardinal seems to be a relevant notion here. It's really a measurable cardinal in disguise. But if the continuum is real-valued measurable then there is a measure extending the Lebesgue measure which measures every subset. I suppose that by extending the co-null filter you can obtain a $0$-$1$ measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a metric space with a two valued diffused Borel measure. Let $\mathcal{U} = \bigcup \{\mathcal{U}_n : n < \omega\}$ be a basis for $X$ where each $\mathcal{U}_n$ is a disjoint family of open sets - See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_metrization_theorem).

Let $\langle x_i : i < \kappa \rangle$ list $X$. For each $i$, let $B_i$ be a open ball around $x_i$ whose measure is zero. Let $\theta \leq \kappa$  be least such that $\bigcup \{B_i : i < \theta\}$ is not null.

For each $n$, consider the family $\mathcal{F}_n = \{U \in \mathcal{U}_n :(\exists i < \theta)(U \subseteq B_i)\}$. Each $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a disjoint family of open sets and if $\mathcal{F} = \bigcup \{\mathcal{F}_n : n < \omega\}$, then $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is not null. Hence for some $n$, $\bigcup \mathcal{F}_n$ is not null. So we can define a total two valued measure on $|\mathcal{F_n}| \leq \kappa$ hence also on $\kappa$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how you conclude that $\theta$ supports a total 0-1 valued measure.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to make $B_i$'s disjoint. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah, all that is used in your original argument is that each point has a null neighborhood.  But that holds for many non-metric spaces.  Take the Dieudonné measure on $\omega_1 + 1$ and restrict it to $\omega_1$ - now every point of $\omega_1$ has a null neighborhood (for instance $i$ has $[0,i+1)$.)  But ZFC proves that $\aleph_1$ is not measurable.

Comment: Actually for that matter, every point of $\omega_1$ is $G_\delta$.

Comment: @Nate: One more reason to ditch choice, and work in models where $\aleph_1$ is in fact measurable! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite follow your last sentence - how do you propose to define a total measure on $\theta$?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{F}_n = \{U_i : i < \lambda\}$ (where $\theta \leq \lambda \leq \kappa$). For $A \subseteq \lambda$, put $\mu(A) = m(\bigcup \{U_i : i \in A\})$. So $\kappa$ (not $\theta$) is above  a measurable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Just wondering if your read the updated answer.

Comment: So having completely forgot about this question/answer for a year, I "independently" reconstructed it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683626/822).  :-/