# atomic ergodic measure

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $m$ be a atomic Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $\phi$ be a homeomorphism on $X$. I want to prove that $m$ is $\phi$ Ergodic if and only if $m$ is concentrated on a single $\phi$ orbit. I tried to proceed like this. Let $x \in X$ and $O(x)$ denotes the orbit of $x$. If $O(x)\neq X$, there exists $y \in X$ such that $y$ does not belong to $O(x)$. Since the measure is atomic $y$ belongs to some atom $V_y$ with $m(V_y)>0$. So for each $y \in X-O(x)$, we get
$V_y$ with $m(V_y)>0$. I could not get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $m(x) >0$. The orbit $O(x)$ of $x$ is $T$-invariant, and $m(O(x)) \geq m(x) > 0$. By ergodicity, $m(O(x)) = 1$.

Comment: will atomic measure imply that $m( \{x\})$>0?

Comment: if the measure is atomic, then there exists some $x$ such that $m(x) >0$.

Comment: Singleton $\{x\}$ with $m(\{x\})>0$ are atoms. But  how can prove that there is atleast one such exists?

Comment: Do you know what an atomic measure is ?

Comment: yes. First an atom in a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},m)$ is a measurable subset $B\in ,\mathcal{M}$ such that $m(B)>0$ and for any $A\subseteq B$ with $A \in \mathcal{M}$, either $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=m(B)$. A measure space is atomic if every element belongs to some atom.

Comment: Oh, that's the slightly-more-general-and-infinitely-more-annoying definition of atomic measure space. Since your space is Borel, this should answer your question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473874/must-atoms-of-a-borel-measure-space-be-singletons