# Defining a measure by positive functional

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In big Rudin's book, it constructs the Lebesgue measure by first defining a positive functional, and then using Riesz representation theorem. It arises me to think that if every measure can be constructed by positive functional on locally compact Hausdorff space, if not, what kind of measure can be constructed by such method?

Comment: Keep reading, and you will find answers in chapter 6!

Comment: What I should add is that given a measure $\mu$, you can of course define a linear functional $\Lambda f = \int fd\mu$.

Comment: @QiyuWen: That's true.  What's more interesting, and maybe what the OP wants to know, is that in a general LCH space, there can exist distinct measures $\mu,\nu$ which define the same positive linear functional $\Lambda$, i.e. $\int f\,d\mu = \int f\,d\nu$ for all continuous compactly supported real-valued $f$.  Of course, by the Riesz representation, for a given $\Lambda$ there is exactly one corresponding measure which is regular, but there can be many more which are not regular.  Rudin doesn't really discuss this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @NateEldredge any example if non-regular?

Comment: The standard example is the Dieudonné measure on the uncountable ordinal space $[0 ,\omega_1]$.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/161396/822 for a reference.  You won't find a counterexample on a "nice" space - on any locally compact metric space, a locally finite Borel measure is automatically regular.