# Understanding Riesz-Markov representation theorem

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Recently, I have come across Riesz representation theorem in this lecture [note](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/jancol1.pdf).

---

**(Gaans)** Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $E:=\mathcal C_b (X)$ the real vector space of all real-valued continuous bounded maps on $X$. Let $E'$ be the dual of $E$. Let $\varphi \in E'$ be positive and $\|\varphi\|_E = 1$. Then there exists a unique Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
$$
\varphi(f) = \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in E. 
$$

---

**(Rudin)** Let

- $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space,
- $E:= \mathcal C_c (X)$ the complex vector space of all complex-valued continuous maps on $X$ with compact support, and
- $\Lambda:E \to \mathbb C$ (not necessarily continuous) positive linear. Here $\Lambda$ is positive means $f \in E \text{ s.t. } f(X) \subset \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ implies $\Lambda (f) \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Then there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ on $X$ which contains all Borel sets of $X$, and there exists a unique non-negative measure $\mu$ on $\mathfrak{M}$ such that

1. $$\Lambda(f) = \int_X  f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in E.$$
2. $\mu(K) < \infty$ for every compact set $K \subseteq X$.
3. $\mu(E) = \inf \{\mu(V) \mid E \subset V, V \text{ open}\}$ for all $E \in \mathfrak{M}$.
4. $\mu(E) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subset E, K \text{ compact}\}$ for all open set $E \subseteq X$ and for all $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ with $\mu(E) <\infty$.
5. If $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ such that $A \subset E$, and $\mu(E)=0$, then $A \in \mathfrak{M}$.

---

**My understanding:**

- 2. means $\mu$ is finite on compact sets.
- 3. means $\mu$ is outer regular on every $E \in \mathfrak{M}$.
- 4. means $\mu$ is tight on every open sets and on every $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ with $\mu(E) <\infty$.
- 5. means $\mu$ is complete.

Rudin's version is powerful in the sense that it applies to even unbounded linear maps.

We can recover Gaans's version as follows. The real vector space of all real-valued continuous bounded maps on $X$ can be seen as a complex vector subspace of all complex-valued continuous bounded maps on $X$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $\varphi$ to the whole complex vector space of all complex-valued continuous bounded maps on $X$. Then we apply Rudin's version to get $\mu$ and then restrict $\mu$ to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.

Could you confirm if my above understanding is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct. However, that the extension to a complex-valued linear function can be represented by a unique measure satisfying these criteria doesn't directly imply that there exists a unique such measure representing the original functional. However, this is not a serious issue; Rudin's proof works for real linear functionals in his proof. More seriously, the existence of a unique tight Borel measure representing the functional is a weaker assumption than the existence of a unique Borel measure representing the functional. In general, it can be strictly weaker.

For general compact Hausdorff spaces, the Baire $\sigma$-algebra, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making all continuous real-valued functions measurable, can be strictly smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Clearly, one could prove a representation theorem in terms of measures on this coarser $\sigma$-algebra. Now, every Baire probability measure on compact Hausdorff space admits a unique extension to a tight Borel probability measure. However, there can exist other extensions to a Borel probability measure that are not tight; [not every Borel probability measure on a compact Hausdorff space must be tight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161337/is-a-probability-measure-on-a-compact-space-regular). In particular, the uniqueness claim in Gaan's version need not hold.

Comment: When I look for the statement of this theorem on the Internet, the resulted unique measure is said to be "regular" or "tight" just as you mentioned. So you meant the claim of "unique Borel probability measure" is not correct in Gaans's version and it should be "unique tight Borel probability measure"?

Comment: Exactly, there is unique tight such Borel probability measure.